# Вирусная флешка. Как запустить файл с флешки при ее подключении?

Tags: windows, usb, вирусы

Здравствуйте мне стало интересно принцип написание вирусов (в образовательное целях)
И мне интересно можно ли вставив флешку в ПК и файл 
Который находится в этой флешке запустился?

Comment: если почитать внимательно про устройство stuxnet вы именно это и увидите

Comment: https://web.archive.org/web/20110128191738/http://www.securelist.com/ru/descriptions/15071647/Rootkit.Win32.Stuxnet.a

Answer (score 3):

В Windows XP (и раньше) достаточно было поместить в корень файлик `autorun.inf`, в котором прописать требуемые команды. Не уверен, запрещали ли там уже дефаултную команду (даблклик в проводнике), но даже если да, почти все вставляя флешку в появившемся окне жали ok и выполнялась моя программа (не вирус - просто у меня была самописная прога, через которую портативные программы можно было запускать) - вот на этом моменте люди удивлялись. Потому что вирусы с автораном были популярны, но они-то дальше открывали проводник как положено, а тут неожиданно прога на весь экран)))

В семёрке, а может и в висте, обработку авторана по умолчанию отключили и популярность вирусов такого плана стала падать.